# How to create multiple stopwatch timers in PyQt5?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a GUI which have multiple timers. When I click one button, it will start a timer and display in a tableWidget. And this tableWidget have two columns which represent number and time, just like this:(each timer will run simultaneously)

| Name | Time Elapse |
| --- | --- |
| Thing#1 | 00:01 |
| Thing#2 | 00:03 |
| Thing#3 | 01:23 |

My original code is this:(not the whole part)

```
x=0
self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.btn)
def btn(self):
    #set Thing#1, Thing#2... to the Name column
    self.newItem = QTableWidgetItem('{}'.format(self.num))
    self.newItem.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tablewidget.setItem(self.x, 0, self.newItem)
                
    #start timer
    self.timer = QTimer()
    self.time = QTime(0, 0, 0)
    self.timer.start(1000)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        
    self.x += 1

def showTime(self):
    self.time = self.time.addSecs(1)
    timeDisplay = self.time.toString("mm:ss")
    self.newItem2 = QTableWidgetItem(timeDisplay)
    self.newItem2.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tablewidget.setItem(self.x - 1, 1, self.newItem2)
```

And what I get is when I clicked that button in order to create Thing#1, and it works at first. However, when I clicked that button again, Thing#1 stopped and Thing#2 started. The strangest thing is the speed of time doubled, just like fastfoward 2x in watching video. And when I clicked again, it's 3x speed and so on.

I really don't know why, and I can't find anything about it on the Internet. However, I do find something about how to make multiple timer in PyQt, it said to create multiple QTimer, so I changed the code to this:

```
x=0
self.timer_dict={}
self.time_dict={}
self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.btn)
def btn(self):
    #set Thing#1, Thing#2... to the Name column
    self.newItem = QTableWidgetItem('{}'.format(self.num))
    self.newItem.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tablewidget.setItem(self.x, 0, self.newItem)
                
    #start timer
    self.timer_dict["{}".format(self.num)] = QTimer()
    self.time_dict["{}".format(self.num)] = QTime(0, 0, 0)
    self.timer_dict["{}".format(self.num)].start(1000)
    self.timer_dict["{}".format(self.num)].timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        
    self.x += 1

def showTime(self):
    self.time_dict['{}'.format(self.num)] = self.time_dict['{}'.format(self.num)].addSecs(1)
    timeDisplay = self.time_dict['{}'.format(self.num)].toString("mm:ss")
    self.newItem2 = QTableWidgetItem(timeDisplay)
    self.newItem2.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.tablewidget.setItem(self.x - 1, 1, self.newItem2)
```

It just for each 'Thing', create corresponding QTimer object. However, I got the same result as the original one.

But I do have some new findings. When I accidentally do this:

```
def btn(self):
    self.timer_dict={}
    self.time_dict={}
    #set Thing#1, Thing#2... to the Name column
    self.newItem = QTableWidgetItem('{}'.format(self.num))
    .........
```

It will reset the self.timer_dict and self.time_dict each time when I clicked that button. It can't make multiple timer, but at least the speed of time won't be 2x, 3x.

I guess that I use self.tablewidget.setItem(self.x - 1, 1, self.newItem2)(last line of code) to update the timer. If I clicked the button, it will moved to the next row and the last row will not update. Thus, I can only have one timer at one time although it should be multiple timer in the background.

And maybe I should use multithread or QThread to achieve my goal? I really don't get it.

UPDATE:
Some reproducible code about my question, I think maybe the reason why I got speed up time is that I use another QTimer to update the current time?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTime, Qt, QTimer, QDateTime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # create the window
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.show_QinputDialog()

    x = 0

    # create widget on the window
    def initUI(self, n):
        self.setFixedSize(220, 320)
        self.setWindowTitle("Multiple Timer System")
        self.center()

        # set layout
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 200, 300))
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        # Section 1: Set Timer
        self.Group1 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Group1)
        self.comboBox1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.Group1)
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            self.comboBox1.addItem("Timer#{}".format(i))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox1)

        self.Button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Group1)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Button1)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Group1, 0, 0, 1, 1)


        # Section 2: Display Current Time
        self.Group2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Group2)

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Group2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.showCurrentTime()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showCurrentTime)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Group2, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        # Section 3: Table
        self.Group3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.Group3)

        self.tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.Group3)
        self.tablewidget.setRowCount(n)
        self.tablewidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Name', 'Time Elapse'])
        self.tablewidget.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.tablewidget.setColumnWidth(0, 76)
        self.tablewidget.setColumnWidth(1, 77)

        # set rowHeader invisible
        self.tablewidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        # ban editing
        self.tablewidget.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        # ban selection
        self.tablewidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.tablewidget)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Group3, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.Group2.setTitle("Current Time")
        self.Group3.setTitle("Current Running Timer")
        self.Group1.setTitle("Start Timer")
        self.Button1.setText("Start")

        self.timer_dict={}
        self.time_dict={}

        self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)

    def show_QinputDialog(self):
        # show dialog to let user input the number of timers
        dialog = QInputDialog(self)
        dialog.setIntRange(1, 100)
        dialog.setInputMode(QInputDialog.IntInput)
        dialog.setLabelText("Please enter the number of timer:(1-100)")
        dialog.setWindowTitle("Multiple Timer System")
        dialog.setIntValue(10)
        self.center()
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self.n = dialog.intValue()
            self.timer_list = []
            for i in range(1, self.n + 1):
                self.timer_list.extend(['Timer#{}'.format(i)])
            self.initUI(self.n)

    def center(self):
        screen = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        size = self.geometry()
        newLeft = (screen.width() - size.width()) / 2
        newTop = (screen.height() - size.height()) / 2
        self.move(newLeft, newTop)

    def start_timer(self):
        self.num_index = self.comboBox1.currentIndex()
        self.num = self.comboBox1.currentText()
        if self.num:
            self.comboBox1.removeItem(self.num_index)

            self.newItem = QTableWidgetItem('{}'.format(self.num))
            self.newItem.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.tablewidget.setItem(self.x, 0, self.newItem)

            self.timer_dict["{}".format(self.num)] = QTimer()
            self.time_dict["{}".format(self.num)] = QTime(0, 0, 0)
            self.timer_dict["{}".format(self.num)].start(1000)
            self.timer_dict["{}".format(self.num)].timeout.connect(self.showTime)

            self.x += 1

    def showCurrentTime(self):
        self.ctime = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        timeDisplay = self.ctime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
        self.label_1.setText(timeDisplay)

    def showTime(self):
        self.time_dict['{}'.format(self.num)] = self.time_dict['{}'.format(self.num)].addSecs(1)
        timeDisplay = self.time_dict['{}'.format(self.num)].toString("mm:ss")
        self.newItem2 = QTableWidgetItem(timeDisplay)
        self.newItem2.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tablewidget.setItem(self.x - 1, 1, self.newItem2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Multithreading has nothing to do with this, the problem is that you're constantly overwriting `self.timer` and always referencing the last `self.x` (also, [`x`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#x-prop) is an existing dynamic property of QWidgets, so you should not overwrite it). The first code should not cause the "speed up" problem you report (but the code is incomplete), *unless* you created a QTimer with a parent (for instance: `self.timer = QTimer(self)`). In that case, the timer is not delete, but since you're using `self.x` for the row to update, each timer will update *that* row.

Comment: Besides that, your code will not throw syntax errors, it is just impossible to run it alone (and you also didn't create a valid row before setting the item, by the way, so if you press the button more times than the row count, it will not work anymore). For future reference, always try to provide a [mre] so that we can easily recreate your problem; remember that *minimal* doesn't mean that it has to be just as short as possible: in your case, the code is just minimal, but is not reproducible.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the help! I have added some reproducible code :-)

Comment: That's better, but, I've to say, that's not *really* minimal, as there are lots of parts that are not important for the question: take for instance the answer by eyllanesc, which is very compact and effective; I know your program is more complex, but a question should only focus on the problem, and you should always create a MRE that explores *that* problem, then you use the possible answers to implement your program as you need. Btw, the current code does exactly what explained before: timers are not deleted (since you create a reference in the dictionary), so they *all* call `showTime`, ->

Comment: -> but since you're always using the same `self.x` to set the item and `self.x` is always increased every time the button is clicked, then only the last row is updated. Besides that: 1. you can use the [`getInt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#getInt) static function; 2. your `center` function is not correct, as it doesn't consider multiple screens (for instance, my main screen is on the right), so you should add `screen.x()` and `screen.y()` to the new position; 3. you didn't consider what happens if the user press `Cancel` on the input dialog; 4. `addWidget` of a grid layout ->

Comment: -> always uses a default row/column span of 1, so specifying it is pointless; 5. you created a useless `widget` and set the layout for it and added that widget to the central widget *without* specifying a layout for it, which is wrong; remove that `self.widget` completely and create the layout for the central widget instead; 6. if widgets are being added to a layout, it's not necessary to specify the parent in the constructor; 7. variables and attributes should *not* have capitalized names (`Button1`, `Group1`, etc); 8. `resizeRowsToContents` is useless if you then call `setColumnWidth`; ->

Comment: -> 9. you should not resize columns to arbitrary values, as you don't know what is the default font of the user (which might be much bigger than yours); 10. for the same reason, you should not use `setFixedSize` like that; 11. use `QGroupBox(title)` insead of `setTitle()`; 12. there's no check for the remaining timers, so if the button is pressed after all timers have been started, the program will crash; 13. you shouldn't constantly create new table items to update the data, but create both items when a new timer is started, and then use `self.tablewidget.item(rowOfTimer, 1)` and `setText()`.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you so much about so detailed advices! I didn't expect many minor issues in my program since many of them were generated by QtDesigner and some of them were written by myself. I'm a beginner to write code and use PyQt5, so these suggestions are of great help to me!

Comment: you're welcome! The code written by pyuic is fine since it's an automated tool (it cannot do optimizations), and, while reading it is usually very educational, it must *always* be done by checking the documentation in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same attribute for the QTimer causing you to delete the previous object (the same for newItem and newItem2). A possible solution is to create a class that stores an access to the items for example using QPersintentModelIndex and for the time use QTimer and QElapsedTimer.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    QElapsedTimer,
    QModelIndex,
    QPersistentModelIndex,
    Qt,
    QTime,
    QTimer,
)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QHeaderView,
    QPushButton,
    QTableWidget,
    QTableWidgetItem,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


@dataclass
class TimerData:
    name_index: QPersistentModelIndex
    time_index: QPersistentModelIndex

    @cached_property
    def timer(self):
        timer = QTimer(interval=500)
        timer.timeout.connect(self._handle_timeout)
        return timer

    @cached_property
    def timer_elapsed(self):
        return QElapsedTimer()

    def start(self):
        self.timer_elapsed.start()
        self.timer.start()
        self._handle_timeout()

    def stop(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def _handle_timeout(self):
        if self.time_index.isValid():
            time = QTime.fromMSecsSinceStartOfDay(self.timer_elapsed.elapsed())
            model = self.time_index.model()
            model.setData(QModelIndex(self.time_index), time.toString("mm:ss"))


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._timer_datas = list()

        self.button = QPushButton("Add")
        self.table = QTableWidget(0, 2)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)
        lay.addWidget(self.table)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

    def handle_clicked(self):
        self.add_timer()

    def add_timer(self):
        row = self.table.rowCount()
        name_item = QTableWidgetItem(f"name-{row}")
        name_item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        time_item = QTableWidgetItem()
        time_item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.table.insertRow(row)
        self.table.setItem(row, 0, name_item)
        self.table.setItem(row, 1, time_item)
        timer_data = TimerData(
            QPersistentModelIndex(self.table.indexFromItem(name_item)),
            QPersistentModelIndex(self.table.indexFromItem(time_item)),
        )
        self._timer_datas.append(timer_data)
        timer_data.start()


def main():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```